# Stripe integration with iOS

Tags: ios, swift, stripe-payments

```
    let paymentContext: STPPaymentContext

    init(product: String, price: Int, settings: Settings) {
       //some other code

        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        self.paymentContext.delegate = self
        paymentContext.hostViewController = self
    }

//    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
//        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
//    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
```

I am trying to follow Stripe's standard integration for iOS and I am using their code from https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ios/tree/master/Example/Standard%20Integration%20(Swift), specifically the CheckoutViewController.swift file but I initially got a error with the commented out code regarding the fatal error so I replaced with the code right above and now i get a compile error that says "Property 'self.paymentContext' not initialized at super.init call" If any swift or stripe experts can help out that would be great!

Answer (score 1):

Update 
`let paymentContext: STPPaymentContext`

by 
`var paymentContext: STPPaymentContext?`